# Reverse lines in file python

Tags: python

So for an assignment i need to make a script which reads in a file, reverses every char in the sentence and then writes to a new file.
I got that working fine, except for a blank line at the top and no idea where this is coming from.
I have looked around online and tried different solutions but all of them include the blank line (which is not on the top of my file)

```
def spiegelRegel():
    readf = open('scripting week 5.py', 'r')
    writef = open('scripting week 5 reversed.txt', 'x')
    for line in readf:
        line = (line[::-1])
        writef.write(line)
    readf.close()
    writef.close()

spiegelRegel()
```

So for some extra info, i did try printing the lines in python in the for loop, and no space is in there so the space somewhat seems to appear from the writing itself.

Comment: line 1 ends with a newline `\n` character, so reversing that line and writing the output will lead to a first blank line

Comment: "i did try printing the lines in python in the for loop"-- do `print(repr(line))`

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks for the quick answer! Any idea how i could remove the /n from the first line? Edit: just tried the rep(line) and it indeed shows a /n i didn't notice at first.

Comment: for the solution maybe `line = line.rstrip('\n')[::-1] + '\n'`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot i have been stuck for a while on this!